# Async Await in a foreach

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem with an `await` in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var role in data.Roles)
{
    var selectedRole = await roleRepo.GetRole(role.Code);
}

public async Task<Role> GetRole(string roleCode)
{
    var role = await _dbContext.Set<Role>().FindAsync(id);
    return role;
}
```

As the code in my head goes, it should work in this sequence:

1. Do Call method GetRole
2. Wait until `GetRole` finished
3. Continue to the next iteration

But in the runtime it goes like this:

1. Do Call method get Role
2. Iterate to next loop whether the call is finished or not
3. Subsequently, the entity framework throw an error like `A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous...`

I'm using EF with webapi2 right now. Can someone explain what caused this?

Update:

Thanks for your response, and I'm sorry since this is my first question that I don't follow the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Main source of problem found though, there were unawaited method in the row before that I don't realize at the moment.
Sorry for the troubling you guys and thank you for your help!

Comment: With the code you've got, I wouldn't expect what you're describing. My guess is that the code you've given (which doesn't even use the selected role) doesn't accurately reflect what your real code does.

Comment: Unclear without a [mcve]. I'd suspect somewhere (not shown in code in Q) that a task is ending up being wrapped inside another task.

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed you accepted a work-around as answer without addressing the questions above. It would have been interesting to know what's actually going on here. FYI, it's [not recommended](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) to mix old-style TPL statements (like `Result`) with `async - await`-based code.

Comment: @GertArnold sorry for dissapointing you about this,

as for main cause of this issue, there were any async method that not awaited or still running in code before I pasted in the question.

And as it's stated on the EF, there must be no simultaneously running query on one context, therefore the EF itself throw `A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous...`

Hope it can help you!

NB: Yes, I prefer use the `async - await` by itself not mixed up with `Result` :)

Comment: The answer with Result is an attempt to debug - it's not necessarily a solution, nor was it advertised to be :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm loath to post this if Jon Skeet isn't sure...but to me it looks like it's doing what you asked.  You've specified an await for var selectedRole...but you actually want this to run in sync?

What happens if you try:

```
foreach (var role in data.Roles)
{
    var selectedRole = roleRepo.GetRole(role.Code).Result;
}
```

This should force your loop to wait until the first iteration has completed. This will help you isolate the problem I think.  It would be good to look at your DbContext stuff...